# Check if Last Character in a String is Not a Letter

Tags: python, regex, string, ironpython

I have a string like so:

```
"A_Origin1_1"
```

I want to remove all numbers and symbols from the end of the string. To get:

```
"A_Origin"
```

I have the ability to strip the number, but not the `"_"`. How do I do this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
def getNumericTail(str):
    return re.split('[^\d]', str)[-1]

def endsWithNumber(str):
    return bool(getNumericTail(str))

def removeNumericalPortion(str):
    return str[:-1];

## IN MAIN ##
fixedName = "A_Origin1_1"
while endsWithNumber(fixedName) == True:
    fixedName = removeNumericalPortion(fixedName);
```

Comment: You could modify `re.split('[^\d]'...` to `re.split('[^\d_]'...)` if you'd like to keep your code.

Comment: Thanks everyone of the quick responses. I will accept an answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just invert your method - rather than removing the last character if it is a number, remove it if it isn't a letter:

```
>>> start = "A_Origin1_1"
>>> while start and not start[-1].isalpha():
    start = start[:-1]


>>> start
'A_Origin'
```

Note that including `start` in the `while` test ensures that empty strings are dealt with properly; otherwise if all characters in the string are stripped it will crash:

```
>>> start = "123"
>>> while not start[-1].isalpha():
    start = start[:-1]



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    while not start[-1].isalpha():
IndexError: string index out of range
```

You should probably have a look at [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); function names should be `lowercase_with_underscores` and you shouldn't compare `== True`.

Answer (score 2):

```
str1="A_Origin1_1"

while not str1[-1].isalpha():
    str1=str1[:-1]
print (str1)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
A_Origin
>>>
```

Just checking the string's last character is not alphabetic.While loop will process untill string's last character is alphabetic.

Comment: Note that this will fail in the case where all characters in the string are not letters (leading to an attempt to determine `""[-1]`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.sub`

```
>>> re.sub(r'[\W_\d]+$', r'', "A_Origin1_1")
'A_Origin'
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `re.split` You can use `str.rstip()` :

```
>>> import string
>>> s.rstrip(string.digits+string.punctuation)
'A_Origin'
```

Answer (score 0):

To match a string not having [A-Za-z] at the end I would use:

```
^.*?[^A-Za-z]$
```